# Android Call Forwarding exception at runtime

Tags: java, android, service

My application get error when called person want to forwarding another person.that is my code blog and my log chart can not get any error or warning

```
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
        ivRedirect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ivCall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
        ivRedirect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ivCall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        ivRedirect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                callForwardString = "*116*" + callForwardString + "#";
                Intent intentCallForward = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); // ACTION_CALL
                Uri uri2 = Uri.fromParts("tel", callForwardString, "#");
                intentCallForward.setData(uri2);
                context.startActivity(intentCallForward);
            }
        });
    }
    if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
        ivRedirect.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ivCall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your LogCat Details

Comment: check my log cat and i saw that json result could not parse string to JSONObject that is my problem.